# How to update a single index of an array locate in another class

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to update individual fields within an array of "Voter" classes, using the array voters to hold them.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj06_Voting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Class requires 1 argument");
            return;
        }

        Voter[] voters = new Voter[12];
        String[] candidate = new String[5];
        int[] selection = new int[12];
        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);

        System.out.println("THESE ARE THE VOTERS:");
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            candidate[i] = in.next();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            voters[i].name = in.next();
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
            {
                voters[i].preference[j] = in.next();
            }
            System.out.print(voters[0].name + " ");
            Voter.print(voters[i].name, voters[i].preference);
        }
    }
}
```

Within the nested for loop, instead of updating the selected index for voters, the loop is updating every index of the array with the same info.

```
public class Voter
{
    public static String name;
    public static String[] preference = new String[5];

    public static void print(String name1, String[] preference1)
    {
        System.out.print("Voter: name=" + name1 + " preferences:");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + preference1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So the output of voters[0].name is changing every time the loop iterates, even though it's only being altered once.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public static String name;
public static String[] preference = new String[5];
```

to:

```
public String name;
public String[] preference = new String[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your member variables were static, it meant that at every instant you were modifying the member values statically. As @Pooya mentioned above, you have to change them to either as the answer or even better (can't modify them without setters)

```
private String name;
private String[] preference = new String[5];
```

If you are using `Voter` as a proper class model in your design, I would recommend that you use constructor/getters/setters to make things a bit more meaningful. For a "Hello World" style treatment, it's probably okay but good practice is good practice:

public class Voter
{
    private String name = "";
    private String[] preference = new String[5];

```
// If possible define constructors where you can supply the preference size

public static void print(String name1, String[] preference1)
{
    System.out.print("Voter: name=" + name1 + " preferences:");
    for (int i=0; i<preference1.length; i++) /* don't hardcode the condition, what if you decided to change the preference size to 3 or 4? */
    {
        System.out.print(" " + preference1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPreference(String[] preference) {
    this.preference = preference;
}

// Define the getters (if you know what I mean)
```

}